# Embed images within mail php

Tags: php, email, mime

I am trying to send newsletter for my web magazine . My PHP code is :

```
$to = $allEmails[$i];
        $subject = $sub;
        $message = $msg;
        //$message .= '<p>To unsubscribe , click here <a href="http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email='.$to.'">Unsubscribe</a></p>';
        $message .= '<br />To unsubscribe , click here ';
        $message .= "http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email=".$to;
        $message .= '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
        $message = stripcslashes($message);





        $from = $from_mail;
        //$headers = "From:" . $from;

        $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n" .
                   "Reply-To:" . $from . "\r\n" .
                   "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";         

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I followed the tutorial http://css-tricks.com/2866-sending-nice-html-email-with-php/ to embed images within that mail . But the image is not showing within the mail !

Comment: Your code looks fine but what is the error ?
and what the mail sent contain ?

Comment: I am getting the mail,but image is not showing. html codes also works fine

Comment: check the image link is it really exists

Comment: remove the strip slashes for the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        $subject = $sub;
        $message = $msg;
        //$message .= '<p>To unsubscribe , click here <a href="http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email='.$to.'">Unsubscribe</a></p>';
        $message .= '<br />To unsubscribe , click here ';
        $message .= "http://www.7sisters.in/index.php?menu=unsubscribe&email=".$to;

        $message = stripcslashes($message);
        $message .= '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
```

Comment: Thanks...its working . But in gmail I have to click show images from this . there is no way to display images always ?

Comment: you can't do that this decision for the user

Answer (score -1):

you should see this post:
[Embed images within mail php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455823/embed-images-within-mail-php)

A lot of clients/browsers will not download images initially. If you want a better experience, you should embed it by including it as discussed in that question.

A good tutorial here too:
http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/mail2.htm